# Cloning Pintos with Ubuntu

Tags: pintos

I am trying to start doing the Pintos Stanford project on Ubuntu. I downloaded the tar file that the Stanford website provides but when I try and run

```
pintos -- run alarm-multiple
```

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized character \x16; marked by <-- HERE after   if ($<-- HERE near column 7 at /home/adambomb/src/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 911
```

I found on another stackoverflow post that I should pull from latest version of pintos:

```
git clone git://pintos-os.org/pintos-anon pintos
```

But doing this gets me an error:

```
Cloning into 'pintos'...
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here and could use some insight to fix either of these problems.
I don't really know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues as you trying various guides on the internet (eg. [this guide](https://pintosiiith.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/install-pintos-with-qemu/)) and looking through StackOverflow. However, this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI5FHJhXv38) helped me the most.

Steps below can be found [here](https://github.com/kumardeepakr3/PINTOS-Ubuntu). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Run `sudo apt-get install qemu`
2. Get latest pintos source code from [pintos public git repository](https://pintos-os.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pintos-anon;a=summary) or download older version with [this link](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos.tar.gz)
   2a. Under heads, find master and click the tree hyperlink
   2b. Click snapshot and download the `.tar.gz` file to your directory
3. Run `tar -xvzf pintos-anon-master-{value}.tar.gz` where `{value}` is the commit-id
4. Open `/utils/pintos-gdb` with vim and edit `GDBMACROS` variable to point to the full path for pintos directory
5. Open Makefile with vim and edit `LOADLIBES` variable name to `LDLIBS`
6. Compile utils directory by navigating to `/src/utils` and running `make`
7. Edit `/src/threads/Make.vars` (line 7): change `bochs` to `qemu`
8. Compile threads directory by navigating to `/src/threads` and running `make`
9. Edit `/utils/pintos` (line 103): replace `bochs` with `qemu`
10. Edit `/utils/pintos` (~line 257): replace `kernel.bin` with the full path to `kernel.bin`
11. Edit `/utils/pintos` (~line 621): replace `qemu` with `qemu-system-x86_64`
12. Edit `/utils/Pintos.pm` (line 362): replace `loader.bin` with the full path to `loader.bin`
13. Open `~/.bashrc` and add `export PATH=/home/.../pintos/src/utils:$PATH` to the last line.
14. Reload terminal by running `source ~/.bashrc`
15. Run pintos with `pintos run alarm-multiple`